# Docker Compose ECS Integration Alternatives

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker

Since integration with ECS was retired in 2023, which was officially highlighted previously, what alternatives can be used at the moment?

Does any compatible project exists? Tried google around, but no clear recommendation what is the migration plan might looks like found.

Even with archiving of the Compose ESC project as part of end of life for this aspect of the Docker Compose, it is still in use.